# Arabic encoding in Java Studio Creator

Tags: jsp, encoding

I'm using [Java Studio Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Java_Studio_Creator) with a MySQL dataBase to build my new small system..

When I pass Arabic characters from the browser to the MySQL database, they appear as question marks, `???`, in MySQL database.

I check the encoding in the JSP code, it looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:ui="http://www.sun.com/web/ui"> 
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

That means it's UTF-8.

I tried encoding like [Windows-1256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) ([code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) used to write Arabic), but it gave me strange symbols, not question marks.

Someone here, called "Rashad", suggested to use something called Servletrequest, but I don't know where to put it. And what does Got, Post mean to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the [database encoding handling?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases)

Comment: Thank you McDowell for your care , If I insert arabic values to database directly without using the browser there is no problem , it shown exactly , but I think the problem is in the jsp ..

Comment: Did you **read** the link? Why don't you tell something about your JDBC URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For MySQL you need to specify the encoding in the JDBC URL](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases).

So, you should **not** use this JDBC URL syntax:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
```

But you should use this JDBC URL syntax:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: WoooW, Thank you very much BalusC for your help, it works. I was working in this problem for more than 3 weeks. I really appreciate you response